# How to exclude some files

Tags: linux, file

I have files default.attr, default.ba. default.cir ..
I want to remove all default.* files except default.cir in linux.

Answer (score 0):

Use `!` in `find`:

```
find . -name "default.*" -a \! -name "default.cir" -print
```

After checking that this works as expected, you can replace `-print` with `-delete`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and probably safest way is to just move the files you don't want to delete to a different directory, perform your operations, and move the files back:

```
TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
mv default.cir $TMPDIR/
rm default.*
mv $TMPDIR/* .
rmdir $TMPDIR
```

This way you don't have to create any complex command and it will work with an arbitrary number of files.